# SQL - Poor design choice?

Tags: sql

Please take a look at the SQL below:

```
create table DatasetToID(
    Dataset varchar(100), 
    ID INT, 
    Name varchar(100), 
    age varchar(100),
    primary key (dataset,id)
)

INSERT INTO DatasetToID VALUES ('Sales', 1, 'Ian Ratkin','30')
INSERT INTO DatasetToID VALUES ('Finance', 1, 'Bert Edwards','56')
INSERT INTO DatasetToID VALUES ('Production', 1, 'Marie Edwards','56')
INSERT INTO DatasetToID VALUES ('Sales', 2, 'Karen Bromley','30')
INSERT INTO DatasetToID VALUES ('Finance', 2, 'Steven Tardy','56')
INSERT INTO DatasetToID VALUES ('Production', 2, 'Eric Bishop','56')

create table Deletion(
    Dataset varchar(100), 
    ID INT, decision bit, 
    date datetime
)

INSERT INTO Deletion VALUES ('Sales', 1, 1, '2013-01-01')
INSERT INTO Deletion VALUES ('Finance', 2, 1, '2013-01-01')
INSERT INTO Deletion VALUES ('Sales', 1, 0, '2013-02-02')
```

A live system I support is designed like this.  Records are deleted from DatasetToID and Deletion at the end of each month if the most recent Deletion decision (bit) is true.  In the case of the above Finance,2 will be deleted but Sales,1 will not because Sales,1 most recent decision is 0 (false).

I believe this is quite a poor design.  I believe that Dataset and ID should be in a different table like i.e. not DatasetToID.  The original developer seemed to disagree before he left.  I am wandering if I am wrong.

Comment: In my opinion yes. There should be normalization of Dataset in the database with a foreign key.

Comment: From the data, ID appears to be a sequence number *within* DataSet. What would be your alternative structure?

Comment: A good database design is a fine art, I supported a couple of systems myself and poor db design is quite common

Comment: The deletion table then can have a complete insert of the record

Comment: @harsh8888, do you mean a composite PK that includes ID and dataset?

Answer (score 1):

It's a denormalized design, which is common in some scenarios for this kind of work.  In particular, a periodic routine like a monthly delete or archive should really not be influencing your schema design.  If this is the only overlap between that key pair, then I would say your old dev was probably right.  If these two columns appear together in tables, however, you are probably right, there should be a master record for this pairing.

Comment: Thanks +1, your first sentance is exactly what he said.  Surely there is a difference between an unnormalized design and a denormalized design?

Comment: How is the first table denormalized? Do you have an alternative?

Comment: @darius, it is the deletion table that I believe us unnormalised.

Comment: @w0051977: I don't see any denormalization there either. I do see that the first table has a *composite key*, which is then referenced in the Deletion table. Having composite keys is a long-running controversy, but it is not denormalization, and is quite okay to have.

Comment: Look at row 1 and row 3 of the deletion table.  I think this constitutes denormalization.  Can you post an answer so that I can give some credit?

Comment: @Darius: Ummm no.  A join table would easily eliminate that duplication of what looks like business data.  So this is denormalized data.  If you were looking at two dumb identity fields I could possibly see your point, but in this case you have intelligent data being duplicated; that's not just a key, that's denormalization.

Comment: @darius: Responding to your first question, the notion of a single table being denormalized is an oxymoron; I don't know what that even means to you. The two tables together constitute a denormalized set.

Comment: @darius: The best alternative in this specific case is probably to create a single-part key in DatasetToID and use it as the FK in Deletions.  This would eliminate the composite key and data duplication and have the nice side effect of getting rid of a possible performance concern due to the use of a string as part of a key.